# How to use local database for creating a fabourite button for my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Quotes app as a beginner Practice project in flutter. I have multiple pages in my app. Right now I want to create an icon button which will perform as a bookmark (Mark as favourite) for the user. And in the app bar there will be a favourite option where the user can find those marked page number. And if they touch it, it will navigate to the preferred page. I am a self learner. So, kinda confused right now about which function should i use. Should I use shared preference? Or SQlite, so that I can create that function for my project? Can you please give some advice?

Comment: Go with [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Comment: thanks brother..will go with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think using shared preference is not good idea for solving your problem so i recommend using sqflite for your purpose and create multiple table for fetching and saving your data.

Comment: Can you explain a bit?

Comment: create SQLite.db file for saving your Quotes(you can see this link for more information about using a db file https://blog.devgenius.io/adding-sqlite-db-file-from-the-assets-internet-in-flutter-3ec42c14cd44) and also create another table for saving your fav Quotes.each time you need fetch and store date to fav table